# Should we do something about "unsupported format character" questions?

Tags: discussion, canonical

There are [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20title%3A%22ValueError%3A%20unsupported%20format%20character%22) of questions about this Python error.

As far as I can tell, they're all basically the same: either a `%` wasn't escaped, or the type specifier (`s` or `d`) was missing from a `%(name)` construct.

Is there something we can do to tidy these up?

Comment: All but one of those questions are from >3 years ago so I don't its much of an issue. Things like [NRE](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+title%3A%22Object+reference+not+set+to+an+instance+of+an+object%22)'s in C# are much worse

Comment: From what I just heard recently, it's really hard to make a good canonical now.

Comment: I'd rather see a single canonical answer for `Cannot encode character x`. It's a good day when I don't see a single question about that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to go out of your way to write a canonical question for something that's just a typographical error. Just close the question and leave a comment. If somebody answers the question anyways, they're probably rep whoring. I see only 14 questions in that list, which is pretty small in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: I'd argue it's more a fundamental misunderstanding of how format strings work than just a typo.

Comment: _"and leave a comment"_ No. You're encouraging these off-topic questions by providing an answer, and you're doing so in _the wrong place_ where your answer cannot be reviewed or downvoted. Please please please do not do this. Either answer or don't, but this middle ground is more harmful than either option.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Leaving a comment about a typo is totally ok, when a typo is actually the cause of the error.

Comment: @Bergi: As I said, it only says "yes, we solve typo problems for you here". Where's the incentive for the OP _not to post those questions again_? When their question was effectively answered anyway? What's the purpose of closing it then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Typo questions are questions with non-working code where the OP doesn't know he only made a typo. We can hardly avoid these, they're indistinguishable from legit questions from the poster's POV. Helping them with their *Doh!* moment is not wrong, we only close them because these questions are not helpful to anyone else.

Comment: @Bergi: Doesn't seem like proper use of the SE model to me. It's a Q&A not a chatroom.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit most of those questions are asked by people who've never been here before, so it doesn't really matter what we encourage, there will be a million new people to ask those questions every day. Given that, closing the question and sending them away with an answer is a better compromise than closing the question and leaving them to join the legions complaining about those meany meanheads at SO.

Comment: @hobbs: Meh perhaps

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo or not, but I would love to find some elegant way to deal with questions where regexp escapes are not double-escaped in the string passed to the JS RegExp constructor, as in `re = new RegExp("\s");`.